# Getting numeric inputs and calculating

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a code which calculates the Normal density using 3 numeric inputs. I tried to run the following code, but the website does not receive inputs and jumps to the the last comment, 'Thank you.' How could I fix it? Thanks in advance!

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.http import *
from scipy.stats import norm

class NF(forms.Form):

    n1 = forms.FloatField(label = 'Input a Number')
    n2 = forms.FloatField(label = 'Mean')
    n3 = forms.FloatField(label = 'SD')


def cal(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NF(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            number = form.clean_data['n1']
            mean = form.clean_data['n2']
            sd = form.clean_data['n3']
            density = norm.pdf(number, mean, sd)
            html= '<html><body>The density is %s.</body></html>' % density

    return HttpResponse('Thanks!')
```

Comment: "the website does not receive inputs" - what do you mean? Have you found that the form data is `None`? Are you sure you're sending the data correctly?

Comment: I'm a real newbie so I donno much. What do u mean by 'the form data is None'?

Comment: None in Python means nothing is there. You would also want to check if the data is equal to an empty string, i.e. `""`. By form data, I mean `number`, `mean`, and `sd`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's maybe because you don't return what you get but only a Thanks.

Change last line to this:

```
...
            html= '<html><body>The density is %s.</body></html>' % density

    return HttpResponse(html)
...
```